# Throwing error while selecting spinner in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am relatively new to android.

When i click the spinner on the phone it is throwing this error:

```
android.view.windowmanager$badtokenexception unable to add window --token null is not for an application
```

My code

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Character");
            list.add("Numeric");
            list.add("Email");
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CreateSteps.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);  

            LinearLayout spinnerHolder = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            spinnerHolder.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            spinnerHolder.setLayoutParams(
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
                final Spinner newSpinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
                allSpns.add(newSpinner);
                newSpinner.setLayoutParams(
                    new Spinner.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                newSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                rAlign.addView(spinnerHolder);
                spinnerHolder.setId(MY_BUTTON);
                MY_BUTTON++;
                spinnerHolder.addView(newSpinner);
```

I have tried implementing the code on a phone running android 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here,

```
final Spinner newSpinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
```

Instead of passing Appliacation Context you need to pass your Activity's context,

```
final Spinner newSpinner = new Spinner(ActivityName.this);
```